# Orthogonal bipolar vectors in 3-dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose the vectors must consist of only 1 and - 1 (bipolar). This binary encoding is common for many neural networks.

Then can two 3D bipolar vectors be orthogonal? Orthogonal vectors can be successfully stored and retrieved in an auto-association memory network (like [Hopfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfield_network)).

As I try to figure out a dot product of any two of such vectors to be zero, I can't find one.

Comment: I don't quite get why this question was closed. However, the answer is simple: two such vectors $v,w\in\{-1,1\}^{2n}$ (in even dimensions) are orthogonal if and only if they differ in exactly $n$ components. In odd dimensions, no two such vectors can be orthogonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only eight vectors in three dimensions whose entries are $\pm1$. The summands of the dot product between any two of these vectors are also $\pm1$, so if the dot product were to be zero there would have to be equal numbers of $+1$ and $-1$ summands, hence an even-length vector. But 3 is an odd number, so no two 3-dimensional "bipolar" vectors are orthogonal.

The same result applies to other odd-dimensional Euclidean vector spaces.